# Functions that are equivalent in linear approximation.

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\lim_{x\to 0} {h(x)\over x}=0$ Therefore $h(x)$=$o(x)$ as $x\to0$. Could I say then that $h(x)$~$x$ as $x\to0$((or $h(x)\equiv x$ as $x\to0$ ) ?
( I know that if $\lim_{x\to 0} {h(x)\over x}=L\ne0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0} {h(x)\over x}=\lim_{x\to 0} {h(x)\over L\cdot x}={L\over L}=1 \Rightarrow h(x)\equiv L\cdot x$ as $x\to0$. )

Comment: So many mistakes ugh

Comment: You can only say $h(x)=o(x)$ or $h(x)~x$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ when the limit is not zero. Or you can say $h(x)$ is in the same order as $x$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. If the limit is zero though, $h(x)$ might have higher order.

Comment: But it is defined that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ if $lim_{x\to0}{f(x)\over g(x)}=0$ which is the case now, putting $g(x)=x$ isn't that so?

Comment: (or some $x_o$ to which x tends.)

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about big $O$. You can say $h(x)\in o(x)$ but not $\sim$ or $\equiv$ if the limit is zero. If it is not, then $h(x)=O(x)$.